# What spice in Asian food makes me sweat and my nose running?

Tags: spices, spicy-hot

What spice in Asian food makes me sweat and my nose runny?

I highly appreciate it in those cases where I've caught a common cold or anything the like, just when the original impact is too low so that my body fails to give those reactions by default. (And it doesn't feel wrong even when I feel very healthy otherwise. Just, somehow, *purgative*.)

Comment: Can you narrow it down to a specific dish?

Comment: It is probably a chili pepper of some kind, not that that narrows it down much.

Comment: I will get some chili pepper and see how it works.

Comment: It could be an effect of a liberal amount of white or black pepper used in addition to chile pepper, too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some health food stores will sell Cayenne Pepper capsules for this very purpose. Some people find that taking a couple will help them sweat out colds and flu. Never tried myself, but I agree there's nothing like a dish packed with heat to clear out the sinuses.

Comment: In the mean time, I've tried Cayenne Pepper. While it it spicy and sharp, it is not *hot*. Maybe the amount I used was not enough (which I doubt) or the spice I bought  was not "fresh"; or, something else is missing.